# Best way to enumerate the types on a tuple?

Tags: c++

As the title says, I'm looking for the best way to enumerate the types on a tuple.
So my first attempt was the code below, which is an adaption of another answer here on stackoverflow, with the only change being that is wrapped on another class, so this doesn't require to pass the tuple type as template parameter:

```cpp
#include <tuple>
using namespace std;
using uInt = size_t;

template<typename... ARGS>
class ECS_Data
{
private:
    tuple<ARGS...> data;

private:
    //TYPE INDEXING
    template<typename T, typename Types>
    struct Internal_Type_Index;

    template<typename T>
    struct Type_Index {
        static constexpr uInt value = Internal_Type_Index<T, tuple<ARGS...>>::value;
    };

    template<typename T, typename U, typename... Types>
    struct Internal_Type_Index<T, tuple<U, Types...>> {
        static constexpr uInt value = 1 + Internal_Type_Index<T, tuple<Types...>>::value;
    };

    template<typename T, typename... Types>
    struct Internal_Type_Index<T, tuple<T, Types...>> {
        static constexpr uInt value = 0;
    };

public:
    template<typename T>
    static constexpr uInt Type_Index_v = Type_Index<T>::value;

};

int main()
{
  ECS_Data<int,float,double,long long,char> ecs_data;
  return ecs_data.Type_Index_v<char>; //return 4
}
```

The "problem" with this is that for a tuple with 50 types let's say, it instantiate 1350 structs and each come with a static variable.
For example, for `tuple<int,float,double>`:
called with `int` would instantiate 1 struct `Internal_Type_Index<int, tuple<int, Types...>>` and stop because `int` is immediately found.
Called with `float` would instantiate 2 structs `Internal_Type_Index<float, tuple<int, Types...>>` and then `Internal_Type_Index<float, tuple<float, Types...>>` then stop because float is found, and so on...resulting in 3+2+1 instantiations (assuming was `Type_Index_v` was called for all types).
So `N + (N+N^2)/2`  instantiation, right?  `N` `Type_Index` and  `(N+N^2)/2` `Internal_Type_Index` partial specializations (all 1350 with a static variable inside of them).

My second solution is this:

```cpp
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>
using namespace std;
using uInt = size_t;

template<typename... ARGS>
class ECS_Data
{
private:
    tuple<ARGS...> data;

    template<typename T>
    inline static uInt _index = 0;

public:
    ECS_Data() {
        init_index(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(ARGS)>());
    }

    template<typename T>
    uInt index()const { return _index<T>; }

private:
    template<size_t... N>
    void init_index(std::index_sequence<N...>) { (..., (_index<ARGS> = N)); }

};

int main()
{
  ECS_Data<int,float,double,char> ecs_data;
  return ecs_data.index<char>();
}
```

Still with the example of a tuple of 50 types, this time we have:
2+N instantiations from `make_index_sequence`
50 static templated variables from `_index`
50 member function instantiations from `index<T>()`
This seems better number wise, but it is runtime now, because I don't see a way to make `_index` constexpr while initializing it with a fold expression like in the code above.

So my questions would be: 
1)Do you see a way to improve the code above?
2)Considering all (for example compiler optimization magic), at the end of the day which version is better?
3)There is a yet better version you can suggest?
**EDIT**:Forgive if is hard to read, the text editor here on stackoverflow completely ignored my newlines.

Comment: Now, keep in mind that all of this complexity is going to fall exclusively on the compiler's shoulders, to work out at compile-time. There is no practical runtime overhead. So, as long as your compiler swallows this bitter pill, the end result should be quite acceptable.

Comment: What is the problem with making it `constexpr`? By just looking at it, I would say that making the constructor and the init member function `constexpr` everything should work. Do you get an error?

Comment: @n314159 yes I did got an error, but I don't exclude I don't know how to do it right so maybe I made a mistake, so here the link if you want to try yourself -> https://godbolt.org/z/PVCgR-  If it works, let me know :)

Comment: Hm, yes I see the problem and I cannot think of a way to go around that right now.

Comment: @n314159 From what I can tell it is impossible to use the approach with a template static member at compile-time, except if one is willing to use the friend injection loophole.

Comment: Do you want/need the static variables? The most straight forward way would be to have a recursive function that returns the index.

Answer (score 2):

I would do:

```
template <typename T, typename Tuple, std::size_t ... Is>
constexpr std::size_t tuple_index_impl(std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    // You might adapt here to handle duplicate differently
    return std::max({ std::is_same<T, std::tuple_element_t<Is, Tuple>>::value * (Is + 1)... });
}

template <typename T, typename Tuple>
constexpr std::size_t tuple_index()
{
   return tuple_index_impl<T, Tuple>(std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value>());
}
```

[Demo](https://cppinsights.io/s/e03ddfc5)

One instantiation of both methods by type + `std::index_sequence` (which might be done magically by compiler in 1 unique instantiation).

Answer (score 1):

I'll only take a shot at 3). My shot would look something like this:

```cpp
template <typename Tuple, typename Needle, std::size_t... I>
constexpr std::size_t tuple_index_impl(std::index_sequence<I...>) {
    // don't use std::disjunction_v here as it will return bool
    constexpr std::size_t idx = std::disjunction<
        // need I+1 to prevent a falsy result on index 0
        std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 
            (I+1) * std::is_same_v<std::tuple_element_t<I, Tuple>, Needle>>...,
        // fallthrough case
        std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 0>
    >::value;
    static_assert(idx != 0, "type not found in tuple");
    return idx - 1;
}

template <typename Tuple, typename Needle>
constexpr std::size_t tuple_index() {
    return tuple_index_impl<Tuple, Needle>(
        std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size_v<Tuple>>{});
}
```

Which could be used like

```cpp
using T = std::tuple<int, long long, double, char, double>;
//std::cout << tuple_index<T, float>();   //ERROR: type not found in tuple
std::cout << tuple_index<T, double>();  // prints "2", the first one
std::cout << tuple_index<T, char>();  // prints "3"
```

Live: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8ea39202298f2ddc

The key here is `std::disjunction`, which doesn't need to instantiate any template arguments after the value it has found. This will also work on any tuple-like type (things that implement the `tuple_element` and `tuple_size` interface).

Since this is obviously all `constexpr`/template magic, the only costs paid will be at compile time. How well this performs in that regard will depend on the efficiency of the compiler's `std::tuple_element` implementation, I would guess, but I haven't done any profiling.